# html pattern не работает

Tags: html, сопоставление-с-образцом

Что не так с pattern в html?
Не работает

```
input#test(type="text", pattern = "(?>(?!текст).)*")
```

Само выражение `^(?>(?!текст).)*$` работает и находит нужные мне исключения, к сожалению необходимо именно в **pattern** проверить.

Comment: Не совсем понятна эта конструкция: `input#test(type="text", pattern = "(?>(?!текст).)*")`. Это явно не нативный `html`, что это?

Comment: Это pug шаблонизатор. Если заменить регулярку - все работает.@Klimenko Kirill

Comment: Проверяйте работу выражение в javascript, если js не поддерживает такую конструкцию, то и в pattern не заработает